# Python - Why are some test cases failing?

Tags: python

So I'm working through problems on hackerrank, I am a beginner in python.

The information about what I'm trying to dois found here: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/compare-the-triplets?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

```
a0,a1,a2 = input().strip().split(' ')
a0,a1,a2 = [int(a0),int(a1),int(a2)]
b0,b1,b2 = input().strip().split(' ')
b0,b1,b2 = [int(b0),int(b1),int(b2)]

a1 = 0
b1 = 0
lst1 = a0,a1,a2
lst2 = b0,b1,b2

for x, y in zip(lst1, lst2):
    if x > y:
        a1 += 1

    if x <y:
        b1 += 1

    else:
        pass

print(a1, b1)
```

So this works perfectly well.

However, in one of the test cases, the input is

```
6 8 12
7 9 15
```

and output should be

```
0 3
```

**However my code keeps failing it. Why is this so?**

Comment: Failing how exactly?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr It isn't giving the right output, and is failing the doc test. I'm not sure what output it is giving, but you can try to do the same on the site, using my code.

Comment: Is it printing out random sonnets of Shakespeare? Exactly how is it failing. What is the output it gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to change varibale name of a1,b1 in your code to some other names.

```
....
a1 = 0
b1 = 0
...
```

They will remove input a1/b1 as the same name, I don't see why that needed :)

```
a0,a1,a2 = [int(a0),int(a1),int(a2)]
b0,b1,b2 = [int(b0),int(b1),int(b2)]
```

Comment: oh wow! good catch, i completely missed that. It works if I change the variables to something else lol.

Answer (score 4):

I find 2 issues in this. 
1. variable names are same. Notice a1 in list and and a1 as a separate Variable.
2. Instead of print you can use '{0} {1}'.format(a1,b1)
Also I would suggest using raw_input() instead of input(), that will help your input treated as a string.